# TABLE vs TABLESPACE , what's the difference?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I want to know the difference between `TABLE` and a `TABLESPACE` in `db2-luw`.

Comment: You may want to start looking here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73441/how-do-tablespaces-differ-in-db2-from-databases-in-mysql-or-sql-server or http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0212wieser/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tablespace is where tables gets stored.

It links the physical storage layer (files on disks) and the logical storage layer (tables, indexes).

You can assign each table to a tablespace to control the physical storage layout (for example to put some tables on faster or more redundant disks, or to stripe tables across disks).

Comment: Simple but understandable!

Answer (score 0):

**As per Oracle Site:
An Oracle database consists of one or more logical storage units called tablespaces, which collectively store all of the database's data. Each tablespace in an Oracle database consists of one or more files called datafiles, which are physical structures that conform to the operating system in which Oracle is running.**

**As per IBM Site:
A table space is a storage structure containing tables, indexes, large objects, and long data. They are used to organize data in a database into logical storage groupings that relate to where data is stored on a system. Table spaces are stored in database partition groups.**